# Icecat install fails with `GLIBC_2.14' and `GLIBC_2.17' not found

Tags: software-installation, browser

I am using gNewSense, but a lot of stuff should be working the same as in Debian.

I followed the instructions: http://zachwick.com/posts/how_to_install_gnu_icecat_on_debian_wheezy.html

The first time I installed it, I could use the `icecat` command, but I had another Firefox installation which seemed to interfere.  I removed the other Firefox installation and the former Icecat install and tried to install Icecat again.

Now I cannot even execute `icecat`:

```
bash: icecat: command not found
```

`which icecat` also shows nothing, even though the directory exists.

```
ls -a /usr/local/bin
.  ..  icecat  icecat-24.0
```

When I try to execute the file inside the icecat-24.0 or the icecat directory I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/icecat/icecat: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/icecat/icecat)
/usr/local/bin/icecat/icecat: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/icecat/icecat)
```

Comment: I don't think `which icecat` will find the executable b/c it's nested in a subdirectory called icecat under `/usr/local/`bin`.

Comment: Well, the funny thing is, that it in fact did work the first time I installed Icecat, but not after I removed and reinstalled it.

Comment: What method did you use to remove the other Firefox and Icecat?

Answer (score 0):

The first error:

```
bash: icecat: command not found
```

Is because you don't have the directory in your path, which is easily solved by using:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/icecat/:$PATH
```

or saving that line in any of your dotfiles (`~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`). The second error, which happens when you try to run the binary directly, tells you that you don't have the 2.14 or 2.17 versions of Glibc against it was compiled the binary, which suggest that you are using Debian Stable or old stable, that don't have these versions available (2.13 or older). There are several approaches that you can follow to archive what you want, I will list them by order:

- Add testing to your sources.list, and upgrade your version of glib.
- Recompile the binary so it uses the same version of glib. (This can be unsuccessful depending the package)
- Use an older version of IceCat.

I wouldn't do any of these and use instead Iceweasel, since it's already in the repositories.